Acidic strength of compound and the stability of its conjugate base
The acidity of a compound is dependent on the stability of its conjugate base. The converse (I believe) is also true. This fact explains why phenol is more acidic than alcohol due to the stability of phenoxide ion.
My question mainly circles around confirming the truth of the statement that the stability of a base is directly related to the strength of the acid that it has come from. More is the stability of the base, weaker is the base and stronger is its conjugate acid.
Why I think that this is true:
If an acid loses a proton easily this must mean that the product  formed is a stable one. For example: The pka value of ester is more than an aldehyde. This can be explained by my statement because in the conjugate base of ester, the carbanion formed will not have excellent conjugation (due to cross conjugation) hence an ester will be less acidic as it will have less tendency to lose a proton to form an unstable product.
Contradictions:
Ketones are less acidic than aldehydes (based on pka) which implies that enolate of aldehyde is more stable. However,if one forms the enolate of a ketone he will find that the 'ene' of this enolate is more stable (has more hyperconjugation) than its aldehyde counterpart.
Further,the cross aldol of acetone with acetaldehyde gives  major product through the enolate of ketone attacking aldehyde that might mean that the enolate of ketone is indeed more stable.
I just want to know whether we should judge the stability of a compound from the acidic strength of its conjugate acid. Also, I want explanations to the contradictions I have so propsed

Whether some ketone or aldehyde is more acidic isn't necessarily trivial, but I wouldn't think hyperconjugation is particularly relevant. Another issue is that aldol reactions depend also on nucleo-/electrophilicity.

Acid-base equilibrium is not different to general chemical equilibrium. The are thermodynamical Δ_r G and kinetic aspects (activation energy). Stabilization of the base decreases G of the base and reaction ΔG , but does not necessarily makes dissociation easier kinetically. It rather makes re-association more difficult in both TD and kinetic aspects.

"the cross aldol of acetone with acetaldehyde gives major product through the enolate of ketone attacking aldehyde that might mean that the enolate of ketone is indeed more stable" This conclusion is not correct if the reaction is under kinetic control.
